# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException exception will running th xamarin UI Test on Physical Device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, ui-testing, xamarin.uitest

I have created a simple Xamarin.Forms(Portable) project and included UI Test project in it. But when i am trying to run the test in physical device it giving me below mentioned exception.

```
Test Name:  AppLaunches
Test Outcome:   Failed
Result Message: 
SetUp : System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : An error occurred while sending the request.
  ----> System.Net.WebException : The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
Result StandardOutput:  Full log file: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest\log-2016-10-22_11-04-53-698.txt
Skipping IDE integration as important properties are configured. To force IDE integration, add .PreferIdeSettings() to ConfigureApp.
Android test running Xamarin.UITest version: 2.0.0.1534
Initializing Android app on device ZX1D63GCCL with installed app: co.veloxcore.UITestSample2
Signing apk with Xamarin keystore.
Skipping installation: Already installed.
```

Here is the link to my project: [XamarinUITest](https://github.com/parth7676/XamarinUITest)
            Log File : [Error Log](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/parth7676/XamarinUITest/master/log-2016-10-22_11-04-53-698.txt)

Comment: How did you resolve the issue?

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/4721 Issue still there

Answer (score -4):

Are you using using [ModernHttpClient](https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient)?
Also you can use [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) if you want to handle network exceptions.
For example:

```
conferences = await Policy  
      .Handle<WebException>()
      .WaitAndRetry
      (
        retryCount:5, 
        sleepDurationProvider: retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt))
      )
      .ExecuteAsync(async () => await getConferencesTask);
```

Also [AsyncErrorHandler](https://github.com/Fody/AsyncErrorHandler) is great tool to handle async exceptions

Comment: These are exceptions that come from Xamarin UITest plumbing. I'm having the same issue. I see no way to apply this answer to the issue.